# only preloader Div background color is not color managed, any ideas why?

Tags: css, colors

I built and designed a nice preloader.

The main div class **.preloader** fills the screen. When the page loads it fades out and shows you the page.

```
    .preloader{
    background-color:#ffcc00;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height:100vh!important;
    min-height: 100vh!important;
    border-width: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Now for some reason, although FireFox is fully color-managed it ignores this specific DIV, which makes my loading animation look bad. See:

[image]

The rest of the site is in perfect colors.

You can see it at [www.zivo.co.il/infmon](http://www.zivo.co.il/infmon) but you must have wide gamut monitor.

I know it's a weird question but I really want to know why this specific DIV doesn't render as it should. I mean it's a simple DIV like all the rest.

Comment: What is the *desired* behaviour? The orange colour completely fills your screen in your screenshot, which is the intended result, is it not?

Comment: the desired behavior is that the GIF animation background would be the same as the div BG so it will blend as you can see in the screenshot the GIF square border is visible (try to open the site in Chrome to see it works as is should)

Comment: You're going to have to use a transparent image to create the effect you're after. I had a similar issue and that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: yes this would solve it but, but I would really like to understand why this behavior is happening why a certain DIV rendered differently from the rest the site, could it be because it has animation?